# How do I handle Rails User Selected Global Variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to figure out how to handle a user selecting a 'global' variable.

Specifically, I want a user to select a location (i.e. state or city) which then shows them all of the posts for those cities/states. I have part of this working, but what I'm really trying to figure out is where I should store such a variable and how.

I know, in theory, what I'm after on the code:

1. User Selections Location (Which is stored somewhere/somehow)
2. Code pulls all posts with that location from the database for display

I've seen a few posts that seem similar, like [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058309/rails-best-practice-for-user-configurable-global-attribute-defaults) and a few others talking about `application.yml` variables, but these don't seem to be user defined if I understand correctly.

One other idea that I've seen is storing this variable in a user session, but I don't want all visitors to have to login in order for this functionality.

Any direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to login to create a session. I suggest you use a user session without login to handle this stuff, and maybe even use a geolocation gem to get automatically the city/state and let the user switch if he wants to.